# Can I disable the MS Word import warning in Pages?

Tags: ms-office, pages

Every time I open a MS Word file in Pages, I get the little warning window that says the fonts aren't going to be perfect or whatever.

OK, Pages!  I get it.  You might not be perfect.

Is there any way to just get rid of this warning forever?  It's pretty annoying.

Comment: Save as a .pages? Change the font?

Comment: It's easier to close the warning than to change the font and re-save a file.

Comment: Yes but you would have to do this only once per file. Or maybe you only take a look at these files?

Comment: I only have to close the warning once per file.  I want to disable the warning application-wide.